# Inserting multiple form data into the database in php

Tags: php

i want to inset these set of data to be added into the database table at once when the button is clicked.
please help

```
<form  action="" method="post">                     
0           
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="HandBag">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="Black Handbag">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3500.00">                 

1           
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Neclace Set">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="Amaizing Green Ocean Beads Neclace Set">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2999.00">                 

2           
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Pants">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="Beige Ankle Cropped Pants">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2500.00">                 


    <input type = "hidden" name = "token" value = "fa31004463eabefa9010eb5d01816913">

    <input type="submit" name="pay now" value="pay" />
```

Comment: use `name="item_name[]"`

Comment: its giving back an error. array to string conversion

Comment: you have to change the php

Comment: wooow! thank you so much. this is a miracle

Comment: you are welcome , someday you will see how simple that is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do that is to use array names like that

```
<form  action="" method="post">                     
0           
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="HandBag">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description[]" value="Black Handbag">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="3500.00">                 

1           
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="Neclace Set">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description[]" value="Amaizing Green Ocean Beads Neclace Set">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="2999.00">                 

2           
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="Pants">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description[]" value="Beige Ankle Cropped Pants">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="2500.00">                 


    <input type = "hidden" name = "token[]" value = "fa31004463eabefa9010eb5d01816913">

    <input type="submit" name="pay_now" value="pay" />
```

the php code will be like that

```
if(isset($_POST['pay_now']){
  $sth = $dbh->perpare('insert into table(item_name, item_description, quantity, amount) values(?, ?, ?, ?)');

  foreach($_POST['item_name'] as $key=>$val){
    //here is the values of the first item
    $item_name=$val;
    $item_description=$_POST['item_description'][$key];
    $quantity=$_POST['quantity'][$key];
    $amount=$_POST['amount'][$key];
    //insert into database like that
    $sth->execute([$item_name,  $item_description, $quantity, $amount]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php code, and form the way mentioned below.

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        foreach($_POST['item'] as $key=>$value) {
            $itemname = $value;
            $desc = $_POST['item_description'][$key];
            $qty = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'][$key];
        }
    }
?>

<form  action="" method="post">                     

<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="HandBag">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description[]" value="Black Handbag">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="3500.00">                 


<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="Neclace Set">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description[]" value="Amaizing Green Ocean Beads Neclace Set">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="2999.00">                 


<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="Pants">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description[]" value="Beige Ankle Cropped Pants">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="2500.00">                 


<input type = "hidden" name = "token" value = "fa31004463eabefa9010eb5d01816913">

<input type="submit" name="pay now" value="pay" />
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: @muzz-art if it solved your problem, then mark the answer so other people following may get the idea and can take the reference